# Is there framework-dependent deploy of .net core app with added nuget packages?

Tags: .net, .net-core

Right now I know of two options:

- self-contained deploy which publishes EVERYTHING
- framework-dependent deploy which publishes only project dlls

Is there intermediate version which packages everything in FDD plus NuGet dependencies? And if not - how it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaken about FDD. To quote [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/):

> Framework-dependent deployment... Your app contains only its own code and any third-party dependencies that are outside of the .NET Core libraries.

So the real FDD is already what you are asking for: project dlls + NuGet dependencies.

Comment: I'm so glad that I'm mistaken. How can I publish NuGet dependencies with my app or install them after deployment in FDD? Everytime I do it it seems that only dlls generated from solution projects are published.

Comment: The `publish` directory should contain all the `.ddl` files for your project as well as third party NuGet dependencies. Where are you looking for the dlls? What do you see?

Comment: As a reference, here's what I did on my machine: `dotnet new console -o StackExample`, `cd StackExample`, `dotnet add package Newtonsoft.Json`, `dotnet publish`, `ls bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/publish/` and I see `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` in the publish directory.